# Сделать синонимами метки [bot] и [бот]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метки [бот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82) и [bot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot). У них разное описание, но применяются они по вопросам с одинаковыми темами, поэтому предлагаю объединить эти метки.

**P.S** предлагаю объединить в сторону [бот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82):

1. У неё описание соответствует теме всех вопросов (и с той, и с другой меткой).
2. Она на русском, а наш сайт называется `StackOverFlow на русском`.

Comment: Предлагаю поставить тревогу "требует внимание модератора". Потому как утвердить синонимы единолично могут только они. Другие могут голосовать, но надо иметь рейтинг по метке

Comment: Заодно можно проголосовать за [FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202754/339911) на MSE.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вроде сигнал тревоги для этого использовать не принято... Но попробую...

Comment: вполне нормально, доверься мне.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синонимизировал [bot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot) → [бот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82), по традиции делать русскоязычную метку основной.

Описание у второй метки также выглядит более общим.

Answer (score 5):

Когда описания нет и используются примерно по одинаковым причинам объединять просто. Когда есть описание с двух сторон, то надо определиться с итоговым описанием. Так как при объединении что-то одно пропадёт (может даже так), что не будет доступно обычным пользователям. Поэтому во всех подобных случаях к предложения стоит добавлять как итоговое описание целевой метки (краткое и полное), так и то какая метка должна быть выбрана основной.

В целом предложение про объединение одобряю.

Comment: я думаю надо объединять в сторону [бот], т.к. в описании сказано: `во всех вопросах связанных с термином "Бот`, а в [bot] сказано: `выполняющие автоматизированные задачи через Интернет`.